# I told SVN to no longer ignore a properties file, but it still is

Tags: tortoisesvn, svnignore

Using Tortoise SVN 1.6.16

**Steps**

1. In the SVN repo directory, right click and select TortoiseSVN -> Properties.
2. Select the property svn:ignore and Edit.
3. Remove the desired file name from the property (in my case it was the only file, so the property is now empty).

[image: SVN Properties screen shot]

4. Click OK a time or two.
5. In the SVN repo directory right click and select SVN update.

**Expected result**:  The file gets updated.

**Actual result**:  The file is still "skippped."

[image: SVN update screen shot]

Other things I have tried include completely deleting the svn:ignore property, and even restarting this computer.

Comment: Does the file already exist in the repository?

Comment: @alroc: Yes, it is an existing file.  It is a properties file, and we need our local versions of it to point to our own IPs and log files and the like, which is why it was ignored.  But there have been some global changes, so I wanted to update, merge, then re-ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked, but other answers are still welcome:

1. "Add" the file (but do not commit).
2. "Revert" the file.
3. "Update" the file.

In that order.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to address a configuration file that everyone has to modify is [in the Subversion FAQ](https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#ignore-commit).

You should have a template of the configuration file which **is** versioned, then each developer makes a local copy in which they make their changes (local IPs, etc.) and ignore that file in the WC.

For example, you might have `app.config.template` which is the template of `app.config`. `app.config.template` has placeholders for those per-user/per-workstation settings. The developer, after they check out the project, makes a (local filesytem) copy of `app.config.template` named `app.config` (**not** <kbd>svn cp</kbd>. The directory holding the file(s) then has `svn:ignore` set to ignore `app.config`.

Comment: This is good advice, and another team member is moving us in this direction, so +1.  However, this does not address the actual question.